# Creating sequential tooltips to show site features to new users

Tags: jquery

I am searching for methods to implement a simple way to introduce site features around the screen at first login of the user to the site.

This could be a sequential tooltips with next/back/skip buttons or other methods. I tried to google this, but no success ( It would be because of my bad keywords of search)

anyone can help or say how this would be done ?

platform : PHP, mySql, jQuery and HTML

Answer (score 0):

In looking for the same thing, I found this: http://codecanyon.net/item/sequential-tooltips/931033.

Seem legit. Hope that helps.